# Why is 'projection' an invalid value for the media attribute in a link tag?

Tags: html, w3c-validation

According to the [w3.org validator](http://validator.w3.org):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen, projection, tv" />
```

does not seem to be valid anymore due to the `projection` value.

I don't remember exactly, but this way Opera in Fullscreen is included.
Probably Opera will load the file with media="screen" too.

Why is this invalid now? Is there another way to give extra CSS to "fullscreen / projection" devices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maintainer of the W3C HTML checker here. About 3 weeks ago, I implemented and pushed to the production W3C HTML checker the change that emits these new errors; this change:
https://github.com/validator/validator/commit/66c739a49afd050226a91f2b7f49662e0dcc9a09

I made that change in order to bring the HTML checker in conformance with the current CSS Media Queries spec. As noted in [an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410984/why-is-the-projection-value-not-a-valid-value-for-the-media-attribute-in-a-link/31411294#31411294):

> [...] MQ4 basically deprecates all the [CSS2.1 media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html) except `all`, `print`, `screen` and `speech`, citing the use of media feature detection instead, saying:
>
> > In addition, the following **deprecated** media types are defined. Authors must not use these media types; instead, it is recommended that they select appropriate media features that better represent the aspect of the device that they are attempting to style against.
>
> Presumably, the validator is marking the value invalid because it violates the stipulation that "Authors must not use these media types".

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.
https://drafts.csswg.org//mediaqueries/#media-types
_"User agents must recognize the following media types as valid, but must make them match nothing."_
Knowing that, I understand your changes to the conformance checker.

Answer (score 4):

The complete error message says:

> Bad value `screen, projection, tv` for attribute `media` on element `link`: Deprecated media type `projection`. For guidance, see [the Media Types section in the current Media Queries specification](http://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries/#media-types).

... and "the current Media Queries specification" links to Media Queries 4, which is currently in development. MQ4 basically deprecates all the [CSS2.1 media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html) except `all`, `print`, `screen` and `speech`, citing the use of media feature detection instead, saying:

> In addition, the following **deprecated** media types are defined. Authors must not use these media types; instead, it is recommended that they select appropriate media features that better represent the aspect of the device that they are attempting to style against.

Presumably, the validator is marking the value invalid because it violates the stipulation that "Authors must not use these media types".

Answer (score 1):

I think it’s valid HTML5:

1. The [`media` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#attr-link-media) of the `link` element says:

   > The value must be a [valid media query](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/infrastructure.html#valid-media-query).
2. It [links to](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/infrastructure.html#valid-media-query) this definition of "valid media query";

   > A string is a valid media query if it matches the `media_query_list` production of the Media Queries specification. [[MQ]](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/references.html#refsMQ)
3. It [links to](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/references.html#refsMQ) this specification:

   > Media Queries (URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), H. Lie, T. Çelik, D. Glazman, A. van Kesteren. W3C.
4. The current Recommendation of http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ is:

   http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-css3-mediaqueries-20120619/
5. The mentioned `media_query_list` is defined in [section 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-css3-mediaqueries-20120619/#syntax):

   > The media query syntax is described in terms of the [CSS2 grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html). As such, rules not defined here are defined in CSS2. The `media_query_list` production defined below replaces the `media_list` production from CSS2. [[CSS21]](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-css3-mediaqueries-20120619/#CSS21)
6. It links to the Recommendation http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607
7. `projection` is one of the [recognized media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/media.html#media-types)